# ReactJS impossible to link Stripe Payments firebase function (Error 404)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I would like to connect my firebase function to my stripe, when I launch locally, the payment is validated, but when I import my function on firebase, I have a 404 error.

This is my server side function

```
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.sk_test_51ITAFxFmQd4mXEjc0FWa4hExCP0v5Qu7GnMDfF6mzEyd8Tv8ussQhUn1ZCVdBDhqsX4IrcR9R00EYXbIvRq)

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/payment", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    let { amount, id } = req.body
    try {
        const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount,
            currency: "USD",
            description: "Spatula company",
            payment_method: id,
            confirm: true
        })
        console.log("Payment", payment)
        res.json({
            message: "Payment successful",
            success: true
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
        res.json({
            message: "Payment failed",
            success: false
        })
    }
})


exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is my reactjs script

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        })


    if(!error) {
        try {
            const {id} = paymentMethod
            const response = await axios.post('https://us-central1-XXX.cloudfunctions.net/api', {
                amount: 1000,
                id
            })

            if(response.data.success) {
      

      console.log("Successful payment")
            setSuccess(true)
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
    }
} else {
    console.log(error.message)
}
}
```

I'll take all the help I can get, thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have any logs you can attach in your question? Where's the 404 happening at? Is your function deployed properly? Make sure your endpoint is called correct, e.g. /api/payment

Comment: Yes it's the right endpoint

Comment: What is the exact error you encounter? What do your server logs tell you? Are you certain the call is correct? The `axios.post()` call in your client code is accessing `.../api` while your server defines an endpoint at `/payment`.

Comment: Ok it's working well with endpoint, but when I test with decline card from stripe I have this error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-ecom-studio.cloudfunctions.net/api/payments/create' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
PaymentForm.js:74 Error Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

Comment: Then it's a CORS error, it's not related to Stripe. Also, I don't see a /api/payments/create endpoint in your code above.